# What CTA color would work best?

Tags: color, color-theory, color-conversion, button

I am just getting into UI design. I have a site I am working with right now whose primary color is #ffb606(yellow). All of my CTA's are yellow with white text. I need to change the CTA color but I am not sure if I should go with a more reddish-orange that is in our logo. Or should I choose something completely different?

Any help is appreciated. (screenshots below)[image: Here is our homepage. I just feel like the yellow doesn't really call any of the CTA's out]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. You should show what you have tried.  We have [special requirements for critique questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/682/89608). Please read them and [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/128361/edit) accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: The small version of the logo looks like a sceptical smiley ;)

Comment: From my perspective I think the jumbotron would look better if the team was a silhouette with a gradient. Another issue I am finding is the flow is off with the color combination. Think you need to step back and figure what your front most features are. I would strongly suggest make a site from black and white in HTML than look into adding a color palette.

Answer (score 3):

All I am going to say is that white text (#FFFFFF) on a light orange-yellow (#FFB62A) button fails the [Web Content Accessibility Guidelines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Content_Accessibility_Guidelines) (WCAG).

I tested that colour combination on [contrastchecker.com](https://contrastchecker.com/), and it fails every single criterion across the board. Choose a different colour instead, and choose a contrasting text colour.

[image]

All the red circles with an X are fails.

Note: I have no affiliation with the contrast checker website.

Comment: Why not just post contract checker as an actual URL? I dont see any issues with doing that.

Comment: @Mᴏɴᴋᴇʏ I have done that now.

Comment: all good, +1, too

Answer (score 2):

For a website CTA you should always consider:

- good contrast between button and background
- good contrast between button and text
- it looks like a button or link

From there it's pretty much up to you what color to use. In my tests usually the specific color doesn't matter, as long as it fits the three criteria above.

In your case, I'd use a completely different color than other elements in the site. Everything is black / white / orange on the screen, so a green or red button would instantly draw more attention to it than the current orange button.